# how to pass this. variable to child function Javascript

Tags: javascript, function, this

The **parent.age** set to **20** so it will overwrite the "**this.age = 5**" of the parent function and then I want  to pass **this.age** with the value of **20** to the **child function** so the console log output should be ( **parent Age 20** )

```
function parent(){
this.age = 5 // this age will overwrite by 20 and then should be passed to the child function

function child(event){
console.log("parent Age", this.age) // <- the output should be "parent Age 20"
}

window.addEventListener('click',child)
} 


parent.age = 20
parent()

console.log(parent.age) // output ->  20
```

Comment: In the provided example, `this` in `parent` function doesn't refer to that function, and `this.age` will not be overridden by setting `parent.age` later.

Comment: can you please help me find a solution or do you have a solution

Comment: Please read the linked questions?